# Report in .NET Flickering

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I have a .NET report, which binds to an RDLC file using a business object for it's datasource. The report take a paremeter which I set on Page_Init. The problem I have is that the view constantly keeps refreshing, making continuous AJAX requests but displaying nothing. I've set breakpoints on my DAL methods and they're only called once, yet the AJAX requests are constant. I have no idea why this is happening. This is my reportviewer definition:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
            Font-Size="8pt" Height="834px" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
            WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="910px">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Report1.rdlc"/>
```

This one really has me stumped, not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you supplied any parameters in Page_Load, move them to Page_Init.

Answer (score -1):

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

public partial class ExportSoftware_Depb_Edi_Annex_B_Report : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bind();
    }
    private void Bind()
    {
        DataSet sd = new DataSet();
        ExecuteProcedures ex = new ExecuteProcedures(1, CommonStrings.ConnectionString);
        ex.Parameters.Add("@intAnnexure_B_Id", SqlDbType.Int, Session["id"]);
        sd  = ex.LoadDatasetWithProcedure("ProcDEPBAnnexureBBind_Report");
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/ExportSoftware/Report/Depb_Edi_Annex_B.rdlc");
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
        rds.Name = "Depb_Edi_Annex_B_DataTable1";
        rds.Value = sd.Tables[0];
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        ReportViewer1.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to mean something?